# Creating dashboard from a report in MS dynamics CRM ?

Tags: iframe, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2012

I have created a report in SSRS. Now I am trying to create a dashboard from that report. I have followed this link:

http://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/embed-website-dynamics-crm-dashboard/

But when I paste my report url, after clicking  ok it only shows the url itself, It doesn't show the report. but still after publishing when i open my dashboard it shows blank.

after that i followed this link:

https://srmscrm.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/370/#comment-1440

it is saying to enter the relative path of the report. But it adds https:// automatically to the path.

How to create a dashboard from a report? Can someone please provide the link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following article describes what you should do to resolve your issue - http://www.powerxrm.com/add-report-to-dashboards-in-crm-20152016/